# Use colorsceme with 'Plot' depending on third function

Tags: plotting, color

First off, here is my code:

```
ClearAll[KappaR]
KappaR[κP_, J_, Δ_] := 
 0.5*(κP - 
    Re[  Sqrt[  -16 J^2 + (κP - 2  I Δ)^2]])


ClearAll[Error]
Error[κ1_, 
  J1_, δκ_, δJ_, ΔRP_] :=
 Sqrt[δκ^2  *  (0.5 - 
       Re[  (κ1 - 2  I ΔRP)/
         Sqrt[  -16 J1^2 + (κ1 - 
              2  I ΔRP)^2]])^2 + δJ^2 *  (Re[ 
       16 J1/(Sqrt[  -16 J1^2 + (κ1 - 
               2  I ΔRP)^2])]^2) + ΔRP^2 \
*(Re[  2 I (κ1 - 2  I ΔRP)/
         Sqrt[  -16 J1^2 + (κ1 - 2  I ΔRP)^2]])^2 
  ]

κ = 40;


K10 = Table[
   d //. FindRoot[KappaR[κ, d, i - 1] - 10, {d, 6}], {i, 19}];

K10 = Transpose[{Range[0, 18], K10}];

FitK10 = NonlinearModelFit[K10, 
   Sqrt[a *x^2 + c], {{a, 0.76}, {c, 72.7}}, x];

MinErr = Error[Range[0, 18, 0.01], 
   Sqrt[(a /. FitK10["BestFitParameters"]) Range[0, 18, 
        0.01]^2 + (c /. 
       FitK10["BestFitParameters"])], δκ, δJ, \
ΔRP];

Show[DensityPlot[
  KappaR[κ, J, Δ], {Δ, 0, 20}, {J, 
   K10[[1, 2]] - 2, K10[[-1, 2]]}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Κ_P = " <> ToString[κ], 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic]
 ,
 ListPlot[K10]
 ,
 Plot[FitK10[x], {x, 0, 18}, PlotStyle -> Green]


 ]
```

So in the end I would like the line created by Plot to be colored in `"AvocadoColors"` colorscheme depending on the Error `MinErr` at that point of the line. I have no clue how to tackle this without being extremely complicated.

Answer (score 2):

You don't provide a valid function, as `MinErr` depends on values you are not providing `{ΔRP, δJ, δκ}`. But for any function `f[x,y]` with `x` horizontal and `y` vertical you could use the option

```
ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, ColorData["AvocadoColors"][f[x, y]]]
```

For example

```
With[
 {
  f = Identity[#1] Identity[#2] &
  },
 Show[
  DensityPlot[
   KappaR[κ, J, Δ]
   , {Δ, 0, 20}
   , {J, K10[[1, 2]] - 2, K10[[-1, 2]]}
   , PlotLabel -> "Κ_P = " <> ToString[κ]
   , PlotLegends -> Automatic
   ],
  ListPlot[
   K10
   ],
  Plot[
   FitK10[x]
   , {x, 0, 18}
   , ColorFunction -> 
    Function[{x, y}, ColorData["AvocadoColors"][f[x, y]]]
   ]
  ]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]